# what is causing this AssociationTypeMismatch in my controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers - `ItemsController` and `TradesController`. I'm building a `@trade` inside the `ItemsController` `#show` action, which is sent to the `TradesController` `#create` action with a form.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @trade = current_user.requested_trades.build
  @approved_trades = @item.trades
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render :json => @items.to_json(:methods => [:image_url]) }
  end
end

class TradesController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @trade = current_user.requested_trades.build(trade_params)
  respond_to do |format|
   if @trade.save
    format.html { redirect_to @trade, notice: "Your request for trade has been submitted. You will be notified once it is approved or denied." }
    format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @trade }
   else
    format.html { redirect_to @trade, notice: "Pick another amount" }
   end
  end
 end

 private
 def trade_params
  params.require(:trade).permit(:trade_requester, :trade_recipient, :wanted_item, :collateral_item, :shares)
 end
end
```

And then here's my `Trade` model

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :trade_recipient, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :wanted_item, class_name: "Item"
 belongs_to :collateral_item, class_name: "Item"
end
```

Here's the form in my `Item's` `show` view:

```
<%= form_for(@trade) do |f| %>                  
 <%= f.hidden_field :wanted_item, value: @item.id %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :shares, placeholder: "Pick a number between 1 and #{@item.shares}" %>
  <%= f.submit "Trade", class: "button minty-button wide-button" %>     
 </div>
<% end %>
```

The above code for the `ItemsController` posts to the `TradesController` `create` action, but I'm getting an error that says `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in TradesController#createItem(#70095717466760) expected, got String(#70095657672800)`

Why is that expecting an `Item`? It seems that if `@trade` creation results in error, then it should redirect to `@trade`.

Comment: Please post the associations for your `trade` model.

Comment: @TomAranda added

Comment: What line of code is generating the error?  I am guessing it is `@trade = current_user.requested_trades.build(trade_params)`.  If so you should post your `trade_params` code as well.  It probably has something to do with the `params` posted from your form.

Comment: @TomAranda added params and also the form i'm using to submit the request

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is to change your hidden field from `:wanted_item` to `:wanted_item_id`:

```
  <%= form_for(@trade) do |f| %>                  
    <%= f.hidden_field :wanted_item_id, value: @item.id %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :shares, placeholder: "Pick a number between 1 and #{@item.shares}" %>
      <%= f.submit "Trade", class: "button minty-button wide-button" %>     
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Also, make sure your `trade_params` method permits `wanted_item_id`:

```
def trade_params
  params.require(:trade).permit(:trade_requester, :trade_recipient, :wanted_item_id, :collateral_item_id, :shares)
end
```

You may have a similar issue with `:collateral_item` in another form.

Comment: Changing `trade_params` to accept `:wanted_item_id` interferes with other model code that uses `:wanted_item`. Changing this code to use that results in a fixnum error.

Comment: I can't help you without all of your other code.  You could refactor your other model code to use `wanted_item_id` or you could the the approach of using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `fields_for`.  Good luck.